# Why do I get a SyntaxError <unicode error> on my import statement? Should this not be simple?

Tags: python, unicode, syntax

Here's my first simple test program in Python. Without importing the os library the program runs fine... Leading me to believe there's something wrong with my import statement, however this is the only way i ever see them written. Why am I still getting a syntax error?

```
import os # <-- why does this line give me a syntax error?!?!?! <unicode error> -->

CalibrationData = r'C:/Users/user/Desktop/blah Redesign/Data/attempts at data gathering/CalibrationData.txt'

File = open(CalibrationData, 'w')
File.write('Test')
File.close()
```

My end goal is to write a simple program that will look through a directory and tabularize data from relevant .ini files within it.

Well, as MDurant pointed out... I pasted in some unprintable character - probably when i entered the URL.

Comment: Could you paste the exact error you're getting?

Comment: From the interpreter: File "<stdin>", line 1 /n SyntaxError: <unicode error> 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: Do you happen to have an `os.py` file somewhere? I bet that you have, and that this file contains a string literal with a malformed `\Uxxxxxxxx` escape.

Comment: I'm working out of a folder on my desktop, no os.py there. a quick serach in the root of C:\\ shows an os.py in an OpenOffice4 folder... could that be the culprit? No \Uxxxxxxx literal there.

Comment: It might. That's what the error hints at. Without more information iis hard to tell.

Comment: Is it possible there's a hidden unprintable character there, perhaps copy-pasted?

Comment: Welllll i'll be damned. There must've been an unprintable character copied when i pasted in the "location URL." I retyped the snippet of code, and sure enough it worked. Thanks for your help mdurant! I spend more time dealing with these kinds of issues than I do learning to program >.<